# please tell me what is wrong with this simple code

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to html. I am trying to get time but the code is not working in browser. please help

```
<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>

<button type="button"
onclick="document.getElementByid('time').innerHTML = Date()">
Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="time"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a look into your console

Comment: F12 is the way. Once pressed go to console tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typo in your code,

```
document.getElementByid('time')
```

should be:

```
document.getElementById('time')
```

(you miss the i capital)

For simple debugging like this, you can use the console of your web browser. Just hit F12, and look into the console, the error will be described here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo here:

```
document.getElementByid
```

should be

```
document.getElementById
```

Working example [here](http://jsbin.com/femosufoloru/1/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Please fix that line :

```
document.getElementByid('time')
```

and change it to

```
document.getElementById('time')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <button type="button"
    onclick="document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = Date()">
    Click me to display Date and Time.</button>

<p id="time"></p>
```

You spelt getElementById wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please Change Next line:

> document.getElementByid('time')

to:

> document.getElementById('time')